# Calculate volume changed

Tags: database, logic, definition

An item was sale many times. I stored with structure: id, price, timestamp. I calculate the volume of item changed in 24 hours, 7 days and 30 days; so I need the initial volume and current volume. I need exact definition of volume changed for each case. Example for 7 days volume change: initial volume is 7 days before except for today, current volume is today volume, is isn't?

I try to find the definition, but not found.